# Pass variables in an iframe url

Tags: javascript

I am trying pass two variables at the end of every urls opened in an iframe with help of javascript.

In detail:
I have an html file `home.html` which may contains the javascript which am searching for and an iframe,which opens `mysite.com.all` the urls in `mysite.com` need to end with two variables which we have defined in javascript
eg:`mysite.com/index.php?var1=a&var2=b`
and I dont have access to server of `mysite.com`.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are looking a way to parse the query string of the current URL from JavaScript. A web search will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Home body


<iframe id="myIframe">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var par = '4720';
    document.getElementById('myIframe').src="http://php.net/cal.php?id="+par;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tiziano picardi,
Thanks a lot, your answer gives partial solution to me.
My iframe url is dynamic but in script it is defined as static.
Eg: I will define the iframe src as google.com and will do a google search and then will click on one of the url in the search results.All these urls need to be end with two variables as ? or #
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to append parameters to the links of the embedded page (in the iframe)? Note: you can't use Google in an iframe (X-Frame-Options)

Comment: If your need is to edit the content of the page in the iframe, you can't (security reasons). Domains, protocols and ports must match with your page